# using the same .jar for multiple aar. within the same project

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a problem: when using the same jaar in multiple aar and integrating it into one android project, the build result gives me the following exception: Multiple dex files define.....

I already tried 'exclude' in the gradle file of my app with no luck.

```
compile(name: 'eftlib_V1.0', ext: 'aar'){
        exclude module: 'iso8583_V1.0'
    }
compile files('src/main/jniLibs/iso8583_V1.0.jar')
```